# Service Worker not firing fetch event

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

As you can see in the image below, my service worker is both active and the file I am fetching is within the scope of the service worker, but the fetch event is still not being fired.

[image: console & <code>sw.js</code> source]
Are there other required conditions for fetch to be intercepted by the service worker?

Comment: It seems that the scope of the service worker relative to the scope of the files it is accessing is irrelevant. However, the scope of the service worker relative to the scope of the page that has accessed it (in the browser) determines if the fetch event can be intercepted. Please let me know if this is true.

Comment: This happened to me and I had to move the ServiceWorker to the root in order to fix the scope

Comment: possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027096/serviceworker-handling-fetch-events-to-urls-outside-scope