# ServiceWorker handling fetch events to URLs outside scope

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline, offline-browsing

My site registers a ServiceWorker which is scoped to only URLs beginning with `/sw/...`.

```
 /**
  * Register the Service Worker.
  */
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
     navigator.serviceWorker
         .register('{{ URL::asset('sw/serviceworker.js') }}', {scope: './sw/'})
         .then(registration => {
             console.log("SW registered. Scope: ", registration.scope);
         }).catch(err => { console.error("SW Register failed: ", err); });
}
```

One of the pages inside the `/sw/...` path performs a fetch to the server to see if connection to the server is available. The address it fetches is `/ping`, a simple page that returns some JSON. Note the address `/ping/` is **not** inside the `/sw/...` path).

```
// Sample of the bit inside my promise that checks for the server
// this is the request that is being cached

fetch('/ping')
    .then(function(response) {

        if (response.status == 200) {
            console.log('%c Server available! ', 'background: #20c997; color: #000');
        }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('fetch failed! ', err);
    });
```

Yet the browser clearly shows the serviceWorker intercepting the request to `/ping`.

From the Google Chrome Dev Console:

```
▶ Fetching http://127.0.0.1:8000/ping Request {method: "GET", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ping", headers: Headers, referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sw/create", referrerPolicy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade", …} serviceworker.js:105 
▶ Fetched over network http://127.0.0.1:8000/ping:  Response {type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ping", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

This is not doing what I expect because I only want the ServiceWorker to intercept requests to addresses starting with `/sw/...`

Is there somewhere in the spec or intended behaviour of ServiceWorkers that says it can cache the responses to fetch events made by pages in-scope, even if the address it is hitting is out of scope?

Answer (score 6):

*Answering my own question...*

Yes, this **is** intended behaviour. Scope is not determined by the address that the fetch is being made to, but the address of the page *making* the request.

The key word is "from" in this quote from [Google's Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#the_service_worker_life_cycle):

> ...it will handle fetch and message events that occur when a network request or message is made from your page.

So if the JavaScript on `/sw/page1.html` makes a `fetch()` request to `/ping` then this is considered "in scope" by the ServiceWorker because the page *sending* the request starts with `/sw/...`.

Scope also includes the original request made by the browser to fetch the page. So if the browser attempts to navigate to pages starting with `/sw/...` and there is a ServiceWorker registered then it will handle that request.